# Form submits without data in unit test

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-material, karma-jasmine

I have a form that uses components from Angular Material. I want to test that the form submits with the expected data. I will post a simplified version of my code below, but basically my test changes the value of an input and simulates a click on the submit button. I was able to confirm that the input value did in fact change and the form submitted, but the issue is that it is saying it submitted with an empty object even though my assertion passed that the input value changed. Why would it recognize that the input value changed, but submit the form as if it didn't? I'm new to testing Angular applications and have spent a couple days trying to figure this out without any luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Here are the versions of some of my node modules:

- angular 7.2.8
- material 7.3.3
- karma 4.0.1
- jasmine-core 3.3.0
- karma-jasmine 2.0.1

**component.ts:**

```
export class FormComponent {
  @Input() loading: boolean;
  @Output() update: EventEmitter<Office> = new EventEmitter<Office>();

  saveForm(form: any) {
    const { value, valid } = form;

    if (valid) {
        this.update.emit(value);
    }
  }
}
```

**component.html:**

```
<form *ngIf="!loading" (ngSubmit)="saveForm(form)" #form="ngForm" novalidate>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input
      class="company-name"
      matInput 
      placeholder="Company Name" 
      type="text"
      name="companyName"
      required
      #companyName="ngModel"
      [ngModel]="office?.companyName">
    <mat-error *ngIf="companyName.errors?.required && companyName.dirty">
      Company name is required
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
 <button
    class="submit-form"
    mat-raised-button 
    type="submit"
    [disabled]="form.invalid"
  >
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

**component.spec.ts:**

```
describe('FormComponent', () => {
  let component: FormComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FormComponent>;
  let el: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        MatInputModule,
        OverlayModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot({}),
      ],
      declarations: [FormComponent],
      providers: [Actions, MatSnackBar, Store],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    el = fixture.debugElement;
    component.loading = false;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should submit form when submit button is clicked', () => {
    // Setting input value
    el.query(By.css('input.company-name')).nativeElement.value = 'Test Name';
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // Confirming input value changed
    expect(el.query(By.css('input.company-name')).nativeElement.value).toBe(
      'Test Name',
    );
    // Spying on update method
    spyOn(component.update, 'emit').and.callThrough();
    el.query(By.css('button.submit-form')).nativeElement.click();
    // el.query(By.css('button.submit-form')).triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    expect(component.saveForm).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.update.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ companyName: 'Test Name' });
  }):
});
```

**Error Message:**

> Expected spy emit to have been called with [ Object({ companyName:
>   'Test Name' }) ] but actual calls were [ Object({  }) ].

Comment: Can you try to change your spy and test to: `const spy = spyOn(component.update, 'emit').and.callThrough(); expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ companyName: 'Test Name' });`?

Comment: I tried this and it is still being called with an empty object